# RotatedRect angle - Strange Behaviour changing slightly camera position

Tags: opencv, angle, rectangles

I work with OpenCV library (Win7 x64 and Visual Studio 2010).

My work consists on detecting a rectangle that often is rotated.
In order to detect the rectangle, I use `squares.cpp` of OpenCv, than I use the points returned by `findSquares()` to create a RotatedRect, in this way:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i <squares.size(); i++) {
    
        RotatedRect box= cv::minAreaRect(Mat(squares[i]));
```

where `squares` is the vector returned by `findSquares()`.

Now my problem is: when I print `box.angle` on terminal, I see a strange behaviour. There is, in this image
[image]

the `box.angle` is correct (it is around 0°).
But, when I change slightly my camera position, `box.angle` becomes around -88°, as you can see in this second image:
[image]

I don't understand why!!!!

does anyone know why this strange behaviour???

Thanks!

Comment: Also print the width and height of your rectangles and you will see that everything is all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on your the order your square vertices are returned. Take into account that if you start at bottom left point, your angle is correctly -0.89º which tends to zero. Whilst if your first vertice returned is the bottom right, you are at -89.1º. Which is the same aprox as 0.89 -90.
It just depends on which order your contour points get returned.
So dont worry, anything that tends to either 0,90,180 or 270 depending on the order of contour points is a good result.

Kind regards, David